# How do I achieve the UI effect of a window pointing to a status bar item?

Tags: macos, user-interface, notifications, statusbar, menubar

I've seen this done on a few apps:

[image]

Can anyone suggest a starting point on how to do this? I've done some work with the Interface builder and Cocoa, but nothing this fancy.  The requirements are to be able to display a window on demand under a particular menubar icon, and have the user be able to interact with it (buttons and text fields).  Not asking for a full blown solution (unless one exists), just a friendly push in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/

Matt Gemmell made a very nice class for these kinds of windows `MAAttachedWindow`

Answer (score 1):

Get the icons rect from the status bar, then present your window based on that rect. Your example shows an arrow (from a png background image), then they aligned the arrow to be the center of the icons rect in the status bar.